# Role of Database/Application Encryption in Web Applications

Tags: security, web-applications, encryption

Sorry if this question is a little broad but I'm trying to understand how one would protect sensitive information in a database which works in conjunction with a web application.

Say an online retailer stores consumer credit card information. The PCI DSS says that the primary number must be stored in encrypted format. Though my question is how do you prevent unauthorized decryption? I see two scenarios, each with a risk

**Database Encryption**
If a developer encrypts the card number column the information cannot be decyrpted by unauthorized database users. However the information then is encrypted to the web application account (or some application account). Therefore if this account is compromised then essentially any record could be decrypted. Is the main protection for this against SQL injection?

**Application Encryption**
A developer could encrypt the information prior to storage in the application-level. You probably have greater security by segregating the data.  Also depending how you build the application, you could potentially individualize the encryption such that their login credentials becomes the key for decryption. However this has complexities such as changing passwords, complexity requirements, etc.

Is there a "typical" implementation that is common in the industry? I know when I go to Amazon.com I need to renter my password before purchase. So are they encrypting data using a single key for a web account, or are individual users' information being encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

Given the card number, I would record the username and time-stamp and generate a random string (also called a salt).  I would then encode the card number submitted using some defined values.  That way at least people who have access to the database won't see the card number directly, and their is at least some effort of protection.  If the database is hacked, the scheme of description might not be as oblivious.  Just like when you hash and salt a user's password.  Your somewhat doing the same here, except with a credit card number, and some defined variables.

**For the Database Encryption:**
I would assume card numbers could be encripted using a static (really long random) string, and a combination of other defined values.  These values would need to be later be recalled in order to decode the now CIPHERTEXT.

Here is how I would go about doing this:

**First,** at the application layer, TO ENCRIPT:

I would obtain the card number.

> $cardNumberSubmitted = "0123 4567 8910 1234";

I would then formulate a password which is entirely unique to that specific record.  For example, we know a purchase may be identified by a few unique values: the exact time it was placed, who exactly submitted it, or a composite of both items.  You can define other values aswell.  Just make sure their unique to that record and will be defined in all cases.

> $password = $username . $dateTimeSubmitted;

For good measure, I would also append a static string defined in the application layer.  That way if someone steals your database, they still have to guess the application password.

> $password .= " your application password here, make it long ";

I would then generate and append a random string to the password.  This is called a salt.  You create and save as it randomizes the entry encase the user has more than one entry.

> $salt = generateRandomString(10);
>
> $password .= $salt;

We then generate your encrypted value/ CIPHERTEXT:

> $cardNumberCipherText = openssl_encrypt($cardNumberSubmitted, $method, $password);

Now, in **your database** you would save at least the following columns:
cardNumberCipherText, salt, username, and dateTimeSubmitted.

At the application layer, TO DECRIPT:
You would query the cardNumberCipherText, username, salt, and dateTimeSubmitted.  You would then rebuild the password string and decrypt the card numbers.

> $cardNumberSubmitted = openssl_decrypt($cardNumberEncrypted, $method, $password);

As far as the **application encryption,**  I would rely on SSL and make sure my sessions are locked down correctly.  If your using PHP there is plenty of online knowledge about how to properly secure a PHP session. OWSAP is a good place to start.